# which is not annotated with @Test or not included

Tags: selenium, testng-dataprovider

I created two classes under the same package one is called preparation the other is X when I use `dependsOnMethods` to point to the test case in `Preparation` I get an exception.

```
class X.

    @Test(enabled = true,  dependsOnMethods = {"com.selenium.scripts.passkey.regression.delegateprofile.Preparations.TC_01"})
        public void TC_01() {
      something ...
    }

class preparation :

    @Test(enabled = true, description = "Preparation: create a new hotel.")
        public void TC_01() {........}
```

Here is the error:

> com.selenium.scripts.passkey.regression.delegateprofile.DProfile.TC_01()
>   is depending on method public void
>   com.selenium.scripts.passkey.regression.delegateprofile.Preparations.TC_02(),
>   which is not annotated with @Test or not included.

[image: Please see attached image...]

Answer (score 1):

The method should be included in the .xml file

Answer (score 0):

The method on which your test methods depends on should also be in the same class than different classes. This will not make the code ambiguous.

Comment: I think it can be done just using two classes under the same package. I try to run both classes or the whole package (Run -> Run Configurations… ) but I get this error: No free nodes found in:[DynamicGraph 
  Ready:[DProfile.TC_01()[pri:0, instance:com.selenium.scripts.passkey.regression.delegateprofile.DProfile@566776ad], Preparations.TC_01()[pri:0,

Comment: Ok. I can suggest a better way. Instead of running the whole package together, create a testng.xml file to launch the custom configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, `dependsOnMethods` only accept method name and not a `class + name`.

What you can try to do is using `groups` and `dependsOnGroups` attribute.

Comment: Its occurring for me without the class name addition as well. Any solutions to that?

Comment: Ask your question in a new one because you will have to share a sample if you want an appropriate answer